# Difference from liquid to solid items

Tags: code-golf

A shape's volume is the measure of how much three-dimensional space that shape occupies.

## Challenge

Given six integers: `[L,W,H]` as length, width and height of one container and `[l,w,h]` as length, width and height of some random item.

You will need to calculate how many items would fit completely if the item was a liquid/fluid... and subtract how many items would also fit completely if the item was solid.

Note: Rotating the solid shape to fit empty space is required.

The input can be read from stdin, taken from args, can also be one or two lists/arrays, or any other valid way, but you can take in only six integers.

And the output should be one integer number: the difference.

Whole program or function are accepted.

Since this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) shortest code in bytes wins!

## Sample Input/Output

```
1) L=3  W=2  H=2  l=1  w=1  h=2
-> for item as liquid : 6 items fit completely
-> for item as solid  : 6 items fit completely
output: 0

2) L=1  W=8  H=3  l=3  w=4  h=2
-> for item as liquid : 1 item fit completely
-> for item as solid  : no items fit completely
output: 1

3) L=3  W=4  H=3  l=2  w=2  h=2
-> for item as liquid : 4 items fit completely
-> for item as solid  : 2 items fit completely
output: 2

4) L=6  W=6  H=6  l=1  w=5  h=6
-> for item as liquid : 7 items fit completely
-> for item as solid  : 7 items fit completely
output: 0
```

## Draws

Just for illustration of how the solid items could fit:

#### Sample #3

[image]

#### Sample #4

[image]

Comment: Do we have to consider rotations of the items?

Comment: @Pietu1998. Yes. I will edit explaining that

Comment: You might want a test case such as `L=6 W=6 H=6 l=1 w=5 h=6` -> `0`.

Comment: @Pietu1998. I've added thanks

Comment: The solid version effectively has things like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems#Identical_rectangles_in_a_rectangle as a subproblem. So even ignoring the golfing getting this correct at all is potentially ***VERY*** hard. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem

Comment: Do you mean that each of the smaller solids (that, I suppose, are aproximated as cuboids) may be rotated independently to achieve optimal ocupancy of the larger solid? If so, it seems like a formidable math problem by itself.

Comment: @dnep. Yes, this is the idea

Comment: But this is not even a solved problem mathematically speaking. So how is one supposed  to judge a program that runs in any reasonable time as being correct ?

Comment: Can the solids be rotated out of alignment with the grid?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy. Yes, but they must be inside the container

Comment: Ok, with out of alignment rotations allowed too I don't even see a way to do an exponential complexity exhaustive search anymore

Comment: Isn't this an NP-hard problem?

Comment: My instincts might be tricking me, but I have the feeling that optimal solutions would always be aligned... still it seems a pretty hard problem

Comment: Unaligned rotations are necessary. Even [Packing squares in a square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_packing_in_a_square) requires unaligned rotations.

Comment: @feersum Wow, this is wicked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Python 2.7 - <strike>659</strike> <strike>548</strike> <strike>373</strike> 355 bytes

My first golf, but still very golfable.

The rotation thing didn't make it as easy as expected though.

```python
import numpy as n
L,W,H,l,w,h=input();bx=n.zeros((L,W,H));s=0
q=(L*W*H)//(l*w*h);o=[[l,w,h],[l,h,w],[w,l,h],[w,h,l],[h,l,w],[h,w,l]];p=n.ndindex
for i in range(q):
 for a,b,c in p(L,W,H):
  for k in o:
   d=n.copy(bx)
   try:
    for x,y,z in p(k[0],k[1],k[2]):
     if d[a+x][b+y][c+z]:raise
     d[a+x][b+y][c+z]=1
    s+=1;bx=d
   except:pass
print q-s
```

But still a nice little brainteaser :D

**Edit: My colleague and I pondered a little more, and we found some more optimization potential

**Saved 18 byte thanks to CatsAreFluffy

Examples:

```python
[6,6,6,1,5,6]
0

[3,4,3,2,2,2]
2
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! Answers to code-golf challenges are required to be at least trivially golfed. You already used singler letter variables, which is good, but you should also remove unnecessary whitespaces between operators. Also you can write multiple statements in one line if you seperate them with a `;` which saves you the newlines and the potential intendation whitespaces.

Comment: Also you only need to output one integer. There is no need to add text to it, this only increases your byte count for no reason.

Comment: Ty DenkerAffe, the edits saved some bytes :D

Comment: You can save a few bytes by defining a new `range()` and `product()` function as a one-letter function like so: `r=range` and `p=product`. You can now call `range()` as just `r()` and `product()` as just `p()`! This is a pretty good tip for built-in functions that are used many times throughout a golf.

Comment: You can also write loops or conditions in one line if they are not nested: `if foo: bar()` This should save you some more bytes.

Comment: I think you can remove the loop `for n in range(q)`,  `n` never appear after that

Comment: the n there (now i) is the loop for the maximum possible pieces.
1 iteration wouldnt be enough :D

Comment: Something like [this](http://collabedit.com/3uw3f).

Comment: I guess you are using tabs at the moment, but StackExchange replaces them with 4 spaces, so the byte count in your title does not match the byte count in your code-block. To avoid confusing I recommend using just single spaces. If you want you can keep an ungolfed version in the post to explain your algorithm.

Comment: since I removed itertools for now, permutations doesnt work, but thanks anyways

Comment: You can use `input()` instead of `eval(v.argv[1])` and drop the `sys` import.